# Repeat x footer background

Tags: html, css

That is my css code:

```
body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 14px;
background: #861520;
}

#footer-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 334px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: url('../img/footer-image.png') repeat-x;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Width of `footer-image.png` is `1400px`, but if the screen resolution greater than `1400px`, the image is not repeated.

Comment: try removing "background-size:100% 100%" from styles

Comment: Yes my body{} have width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-size: 100% 100%;` will mean the image will automatically scale to fit its container.

If you remove this style, you should see the image repeat.

If you want it to scale to the height of the footer, then you can perhaps try styling it `background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: Well you should remove it anyway, or set it to auto (if the style is being inherited) because it definitely won't repeat with that in there. If there is no other code that could affect it that you haven't shown us, then the only other thing would be to check your caching.

Answer (score 0):

I think the inherited style stops the image being repeated so try removing the 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 14px;
background: #861520;
}

#footer-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 334px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border:1px solid;
  background:url(beautiful-life-hd-hd-wallpapers.jpg) repeat-x;
  background-size:auto;
}
```

as if you will put background size is 100% 100% then it will spread x * y and if you will do 100% den all so try this and may be it is answered already but i think now you will understand...thanx